# MUI Grid not working on any size in a dialog

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

SO im using a MUI dialog, and MUI grid together. I took this code directly from the website. The only changes are the box wrapping the dialog, and the slight change in the dialog functions IE 'openDialog' instead of 'open'. No matter what size I change the dialog to, the grid items remain in a three-column layout, when at 'xs' for example, they should stack to 12. I have no idea why, the code looks right to me.

```
      <Box sx={{flexGrow: 1}}>

        <Dialog
          fullWidth={fullWidth}
          maxWidth={maxWidth}
          open={openDialog}
          onClose={handleCloseDialog}
        >
          <DialogTitle>Optional sizes</DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent>
            <DialogContentText>
              You can set my maximum width and whether to adapt or not.
            </DialogContentText>
            <Box
              noValidate
              component="form"
              sx={{
                display: 'flex',
                flexDirection: 'column',
                m: 'auto',
                width: 'fit-content',
              }}
            >
              <FormControl sx={{ mt: 2, minWidth: 120 }}>
                <InputLabel htmlFor="max-width">maxWidth</InputLabel>
                <Select
                  autoFocus
                  value={maxWidth}
                  onChange={handleMaxWidthChange}
                  label="maxWidth"
                  inputProps={{
                    name: 'max-width',
                    id: 'max-width',
                  }}
                >
                  <MenuItem value={false}>false</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value="xs">xs</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value="sm">sm</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value="md">md</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value="lg">lg</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value="xl">xl</MenuItem>
                </Select>
              </FormControl>
              <FormControlLabel
                sx={{ mt: 1 }}
                control={
                  <Switch checked={fullWidth} onChange={handleFullWidthChange} />
                }
                label="Full width"
              />
            </Box>
            <Grid container>
              <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
                <Grid container spacing={{ xs: 2, md: 3 }}>
                  {Array.from(Array(6)).map((_, index) => (
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={4} md={4} key={index}>
                      <Item>xs=2</Item>
                    </Grid>
                  ))}
                </Grid>
              </Box>
            </Grid>
          </DialogContent>
          <DialogActions>
            <Button onClick={handleCloseDialog}>Close</Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is because the `Grid` is changing layout based on responsive breakpoints of the viewport, instead of the container width. In the posted code, the `Grid` should change to just 1 column when the window is actually resized below `sm`, which is 600px.

If the purpose is to mock the responsive sizes, perhaps for a demo, consider to have `Grid` take value on conditions calculated from the selected `maxWidth` and `fullWidth`, instead of the actual viewport width.

Minimized demo on: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mndi5a?file=src/App.js) (might need to view in new tab for changes).

```
<Grid container spacing={{ xs: 2, md: 3 }}>
  {Array.from(Array(6)).map((_, index) => {
    const responsive = { xs: 12, sm: 4, md: 4, lg: 2, xl: 2 };
    const selected = responsive[`${maxWidth}`] || 0;
    const mockedResponsive = Object.keys(responsive).reduce(
      (acc, cur) =>
        !fullWidth
          ? {
              ...acc,
              [cur]: Math.max(
                responsive[cur],
                Math.max(selected, responsive["md"])
              ),
            }
          : { ...acc, [cur]: Math.max(responsive[cur], selected) },
      {}
    );
    return (
      <Grid item key={index} {...mockedResponsive}>
        <Typography>xs=2</Typography>
      </Grid>
    );
  })}
</Grid>
```